# How do you make nice consonant/vowel charts and tables?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, formatting

Wikipedia has some nice vowel charts, available at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_vowel_charts.

Example (Korean vowels):

[image: Korean vowels]

Example (Australian English diphthongs):

[image: AuE diphthongs]

Similarly, there are vowel and consonant charts in tabular form; Markdown doesn't seem to support tables easily.

Example (Ubykh consonants):

[image: Ubykh consonants]

**How should we produce charts like these and use them in Markdown?** While it's possible to take screenshots as I've done here, that is hard to use, and hard to edit the output, so it's not a good solution.

I see that the UX Stack Exchange has integrated a [UI mockup editor](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange). Perhaps something similar could be added on Linguistics (and maybe the sites on specific languages).

Comment: Interesting... If you want to ask for the feature, tag it with `feature-request` and remove `support`, as there is no such feature.

Comment: I've had some luck _making_ vowel charts in LaTeX using Tikz, not sure how easily you could take them from that .pdf format and put them onto here though.